# How to replace line of text

Tags: java, text, file-io

I am trying to replace a specific line of text in a file. I am having an issue as the below code changes every ID on each line of code.

```
String filepath       = "data.txt";
String newID          = textFId.getText()
String newRoadName    = textFRname.getText();
String newRoadNumber  = textFRnumber.getText();
String newCarType     = textFCartype.getText();

String tempFile = "datatemp.txt";
File oldFile = new File(filepath);
File newFile = new File(tempFile);

String ID         = "";
String RoadName   = "";
String RoadNumber = "";
String CarType    = "";

try {

 FileWriter     fw = new FileWriter(tempFile, true);
 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
 PrintWriter    pw = new PrintWriter(bw);

 x = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
 x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

 while(x.hasNext()) {
 ID         = x.next();
 RoadName   = x.next();
 RoadNumber = x.next();
 CarType    = x.next();

      if(ID.equals(newID)) {
 System.out.println(newID);
 pw.println(newID + "," + newRoadName + "," + newRoadNumber + "," + newCarType);
 } else {
 pw.println(ID + "," + RoadName + "," + RoadNumber + "," + CarType);
 System.out.println(newID);
 }

 }
 x.close();
 pw.flush();
 pw.close();
 oldFile.delete();
 File dump = new File(filepath);
 newFile.renameTo(dump);
 }

 catch (Exception e3){
 System.out.println("UPDATE ERROR!!");
 }
```

And my text file is this:

```
1,PO,100,GB
2,PO,101,GB
3,PO,102,GB
4,PO,103,GB
```

And my output should be this when I update a line:

```
1,PO,100,GB
2,PO,101,GB
3,PO,102,GB
4,PO,104,GB
```

However my output turns out to be this:

```
4,PO,104,GB
4,PO,104,GB
4,PO,104,GB
4,PO,104,GB
```

Comment: Shouldn't newID be equal to .next() in there somewhere? Clean your code a little nicer as @TomBunting said

Comment: You'll find you get more helpful answers by ensuring your code is clean, concise and compiles (even if it currently doesn't do what you expect) - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This seems working. What's the problem?

Comment: Just use `Files.readAllLines`. Much easier

Comment: The code should update one part of the row. I need to be able to update each part of the line right now for some reason if I try and update the ID part of the line to a different number it changes EVERY ID on each line to the same number. I also want to be able to change any part of the line. I have user text fields in my JTable to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This part is what we're not following:

```
    String newID          = textFId.getText()
    String newRoadName    = textFRname.getText();
    String newRoadNumber  = textFRnumber.getText();
    String newCarType     = textFCartype.getText();
```

Where's textFId, textFRname, textFRnumber and textFCartype from?

Comment: Those parts are from the following which is textfields: `btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             
// i = the index of the selected row
int i = table.getSelectedRow();
                
if(i >= 0) {
model.setValueAt(textFId.getText(), i, 0);
model.setValueAt(textFRname.getText(), i, 1);
model.setValueAt(textFRnumber.getText(), i, 2);
model.setValueAt(textFCartype.getText(), i, 3);
}`

Comment: Sorry I was trying to format this answer and having difficulty...the code is from the button.

Comment: `String newID = textFId.getText()` refers to a textfield user input field and when the update button is clicked it updates the data in that part of the row